# Problema con option -php | mysql-

Tags: php, mysql, select, options

una duda simple ojala me puedan ayudar, para completar un select rescato los datos en la BD y los inyecto en los option, mi duda es que cuando aparecen en pantalla aparece un campo vació al inicio y de bajo las opciones que carga la consulta, ¿como se elimina ese campo en blanco? este es el código:

```
<select class="form-control" name="con_cv_tipo" id="con_cv_tipo" required>


<?  

$con_cv_tipo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM mtn_proveedores_contactos_tipo WHERE 
tipo_empresa='$_SESSION[SYS_empresa_id]' ORDER BY tipo_id ASC");

while($tiposPro = $con_cv_tipo ->fetch_array())
{


?>

<option value="<? echo $tiposPro['tipo_id'];?>"><? echo $tiposPro['tipo_descripcion'];?></option>



<?
};
?>

</select>
```

Comment: Prueba agregando esta línea de código después de la etiqueta de apertura del `select` y antes de iniciar el código `php`... `<option value="" hidden>Selecciona un Tipo</option>`

Comment: lo intente y no me funciono, igual gracias por el aporte :)

Comment: ¿Ya comprobaste que no exista un registro con `tipo_descripcion` vacio relacionado a la empresa en cuestion?